# passing session variables through header

Tags: php, html

How can I pass two session variables to `loan_officer1.php` in below code

```
    function redirect_to($location = NULL){
        if($location != NULL){
        header("Location:{$location}");
        exit;
        }
    }

    if(mysql_query($query,$connection)){
        //sucess
        redirect_to('loan_officer1.php');
        }else{
        confirm_query($query);
        }
```

Comment: Session variables don't have to be passed explicitly, they're automatically available to all pages on the site.

Comment: When the loan_officer1.php page is displayed using this redirection, the values of session variables are not displaying. Here what is happening is like going back to previous page.

Comment: Then you're not using the session properly. Make sure all the pages begin with `session_start()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use sessions in php then you don't need to pass session variables explicitly.

You can declare session variables suppose on your index page as

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_Session['loan_officer_name'] = 'ABC DEF';
  $_Session['loan_officer_post'] = 'Officer';
?>
```

and then just call your session variables wherever on any page you need to call like

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_Session['loan_officer_name'];
?>
```

Remember to call session_start(); on page you want to access session variables.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass the..just use this in your **loan_officer1.php**
`$_SESSION['name']` and it will give you the value stored in it

Answer (score 0):

Just give the value to $_SESSION
For ex,like $_SESSION['location']